# Is there a CFHTMLHEAD equivalent for CFSCRIPT?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

This question was asked and answered more than a year ago. Since then, ColdFusion 10 was released but documentation is poor. This question is strictly about ColdFusion 10 and CFSCRIPT.

I am interested in writing this code solely in CFSCRIPT with **absolutely** no CFHTMLHEAD tag being used.

```
<cffunction name="HTMLHead" output="false" returnType="void">
    <cfargument name="text" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfhtmlhead text="#text#">
</cffunction>
```

Here's how I think it **should** work

```
// CREATE PAGE TITLE 
function createPageTitle(Content) {
    LOCAL.Content = ARGUMENTS.Content;
    LOCAL.Content = "<title>#LOCAL.Content#</title>";
    LOCAL.Content = htmlhead(LOCAL.Content);
}
```

I cannot find any documentation on how this is done, but it seems like it would be one of the first things to be included in CFSCRIPT.

Comment: You might wanna go vote for this: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3350719. It won't help your situation this time, but it will help people in the future.

Comment: The [list of new functions for ColdFusion 10](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WS890819DC-DE4D-4b24-A237-6E3483E9D6A1.html) doesn't list anything that touches the HTML `<head>` section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is. BUt have you looked at the [CFScript Community Components](https://github.com/CFCommunity/CFScript-Community-Components) project on GitHub? There is an implementation of [cfhtmlhead](https://github.com/CFCommunity/CFScript-Community-Components/blob/master/htmlhead.cfc) there.

Comment: But that project works on CF9, last I heard. Or do you mean that's why you use it?

Comment: never seen the project before, so it will be useful. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't quite answer the question, but I think you might have pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

That CFScript Community Project stuff will *work*, but looking at how they've implemented `<cfhtmlhead>` I cringe a bit.

But I'd go with the spirit of what they're doing and write a UDF, but I'd just as-closely emulate how `<cfhtmlhead>` is implemented as possible:

```
<cffunction name="cfHtmlHead">
    <cfhtmlhead attributecollection="arguments">
</cffunction>
```

(I'd also dolly it up with returntype / access / output / a `<cfargument>` tag etc).

I do maintain a CFML.cfc for my coding that fills in the blanks for older versions of ColdFusion I run which doesn't have as much CFScript readiness, but it's just a function lib, full of UDFs like that.  I do not implement individual CFCs that needs to be instantiated, and the way the function equivalent of the tag is called bears no relation to the way the tag is called.  That's confused and poorly designed IMO.

Mileage varies, obviously.

Comment: This would be the easiest soultion it think, but the OP did say `I am interested in writing this code solely in CFSCRIPT with ABSOLUTELY no CFHTMLHEAD tag being used.`

Comment: Sure. But given one can't do that, one needs to suggest something one CAN do.  At some point one is going to need to break down to tags to implement a script-friendly version of what is only provided in tags.

Comment: I eagerly await your pull request. Please try to keep in mind that we attempt to support back to CF8.

Comment: Chuckle. Well my approach to the problem at hand would be completely different from yours, so I think we can just agree to disagree as to the approach.  I'm not saying yours is wrong, just that mine would be... not the same.  Equally: as discussed when you commenced the project, I believe this sort of thing is for Adobe to do (or "should have already done"), not the community. Good work doing it though (meant sincerely).

Answer (score 4):

If one didn't want to fall back to using UDFs that wrap up the tag-based functionality, then one could insert the stuff that needs to go into the `<head>` block at the end of the request, by having a look in the output buffer, finding the closing `</head>` tag, and inserting the [stuff] into the buffer just before it.

I *think* the output buffer lives in `getPageContext().getOut()`. There's some methods in there to monkey with it.  Fortunately Elliott Sprehn's already done the leg work on this one, and there's a comment on Ben Nadel's blog as to how to do it: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/758-ColdFusion-GetPageContext-Massive-Exploration.htm (scroll down down down to [Elliott's third comment](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/758-ColdFusion-GetPageContext-Massive-Exploration.htm#comments_4578)).

That said... I recommend this for the sake of "proof of concept", and I'd still go with the tag-based UDF wrapper approach.